# How to change the style of a ProgressBar in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

Is it possible to change the style that the current Windows set to the ProgressBar? I just don't like the normal ProgressBar of the Windows 7...

I searched many places and i just find how to change the color, not the style.

Comment: What do *you* mean by style.  For the most part, it is what it is.

Comment: I just want a progressbar without the blinking and the dimming, just a solid color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can help but it's just easy with the use of two **Panel** controls.. combined with this code: `Panel2.Size = New Size((Math.Truncate(YourPercentage) * Panel1.Width) / 100, 12)` The Panel2 must be inside the Panel1 and it's width must be zero in the beginning then dock it to the left. You can design your "progressbar" because it's a panel. You can change it's color, put a background image. Gives you more flexibility in terms of design compared to ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Disable in the Project Properties the option "Enable XP Visual Styles" and then choose the ForeColor, that will make a solid color ProgressBar.

Comment: That will make all your forms look like 1998.

Comment: @LarsTech All the forms are without border and the buttons are solid color too, I didnt find any diference in the styles that would change visually